# Advice on Spring boot Server config

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I‘m not new in either Spring boot or Spring Security but I am in Spring Authentication‘s Server.

### Description

I have tree apps:

- a spring boot backend,
- a flutter frontend and
- a Keycloak for authentification.

The Backend has only one login method, that is oauth2 and is client of Keycloak. The login method for the Backend is already implemented and is working, using Authorization code.

The flutter should also log into the Backend using Authorization code, but this part is not yet implemented.

The Backend is the part I‘m responsible of and the workflow should be following:

1. The user on Flutter tries to login
2. The Flutter App then requests login from Backend App
3. Backend App, as an authorization server with only one login method which is Keycloak, redirects the user to Keycloak.
4. The first authentification and authorization happens on Keycloak.
5. The Keycloak redirect the user on the Backend.
6. The Backend finds out who the user is and authorizes him.
7. The Backend redirect the user to Flutter‘s scheme and then flutter open (or continue).
8. The Flutter calls the Backend to get tokens.

Now my question is how should I configure the Backend, so that it behaves as Authorization‘s server?

### This I what I‘ve tried.

I‘ve used the newly created `spring-authorization-server`. So my SecurityFilterChain already contains:

```java
…
http
   .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
…
```

Now my backend is resource server for itself and client of itself (I can‘t dissociate it now). So I‘m thinking of

- adding `.oauth2ResourceServer` with the configuration of this same server for verifying the tokens I will issue, and
- adding `.oauth2Client` with again the configurations pointing to this server, for the Flutter app being able to login.

Now I don‘t know how to turn my backend into Autorization server, and to be more precise, how to turn on authorization code for user login.

Thanks for reading. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if Spring Authorization Server works well as a client and resource server. However, you can try the samples and mix them together. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration